# Node Express res.set() not working

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, response, response-headers

I'm implementing `jwt` `bearer` on my app. On my route controller block I have this :

```
utils.createToken({ email: user.email}, function(token){
    res.set({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token});
    res.status(200).json(user);
})
```

But on the response object there's nothing on the `header` : 
[image]

What did I missed? Thanks.

Comment: Are you viewing this result in the browser's console? That `headers` field is a function: have you tried calling `headers('Authorization')` or expanding the "function scope" item to see if there is a value in it?

Comment: I tried `console.log(response.headers())` on the browser and I got the whole headers contents. Thanks. Could you compose an answer for future references? Thanks. :) @pmcoltrane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing obviously wrong with the Express server-side code to set the header.

The `headers` field shown in the response object is a function that returns a header or headers. Calling `console.log(response.headers())` in the browser will show the full response header contents.